# what causes android emulator work slow

Tags: android

what causes android emulator work slow ?

is it because of: 1. Downloading all libraries available in sdk 2. Using latest version of sdk 3. Device specification like screen size, Memory Option (RAM), Internal Storage, or SD Card. 4. or something else other than above mentioned.

I have no idea, please do share your knowledge.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It seems depends on your hardware, dont give the emul 1GB of RAM when your laptop only have 2

Comment: Check if you installed HAXM

Comment: Post questions here about what have you tried and not working. People can give you proper answers

Comment: You might want to try Genymotion, people said its faster

Answer (score 3):

Try using oracle virtual Andro Virtual Machine. It is much faster than native Emulators comes with SDK. Only dis-advantage with oracle VM is, it doesn't have a GPU (requires for game development etc). [See this link to install VM][1]http://wcrosstechnologies2.blogspot.com/2013/06/androvm-how-to-install-and-run.html

Answer (score 0):

emulator is one type of virtual box..thats why its obvious slow down speed..
please see this link..that help you better.
[down speed emulator](http://delphi.org/2013/11/8-tips-to-speed-up-your-android-arm-emulator-avd/)

Answer (score 0):

Yusuf,

There are two types of emulators, ARM-based, and Intel-based. Google's ADT includes an ARM emulator. This emulator contains a virtual ARM processor. It runs ARM machine code. I'm talking about emulating all the ARM registers, FPU, machine instruction codes; all that stuff. It's a 100% software driven, virtual ARM processor. That's really slow.

The other emulator is from Intel. It runs true Intel x86 or x64 machine code natively on your computer's CPU. It's called [HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager). You can read more about it, here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

You can download the Intel HAXM through the Android [SDK Manager](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html), or directly from the Intel HAXM website I taked about above.
[image: Android SDK Manager]
Note: All the Android SDK Manager does is download the executable. Be sure to actually go to your `<sdk>\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager` directory and run the `intelhaxm-android.exe` executable. You need to do this to actually install the emulator.

Once you've install the Intel HAXM, you will want to create your own [AVD](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/avd-manager.html). The Intel HAXM website has some very good instructions on how to create a new AVD: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture

I hope someone finds this useful...

Comment: thanks 
I have installed the HAXM in my laptop with a processor Core I5 and 6GB of RAM but Android Emulator is still slow, it stop on screen with the animated word: android.  
Note (the SDK version is 21 )